# Adobe reader DC text rendering problems?

Tags: pdf

I recently "upgraded" to Adobe reader DC on PC (windows 7) and now I'm having trouble with how the software renders text. To be more specific, when I'm using the Hand Tool to scroll, it won't render the text "smoothly" until I've released the left click button, making it very hard to understand what am I reading. Here's a before and after picture:

Before releasing:
[image: Before]

After releasing:
[image: After]

As you can see, the same first paragraph looks ugly in the first pic and smooth on the second. This didn't happen on Adobe reader XI. Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks!

PS: Of course I've tried the text rendering options, it's on "For Laptop/LCD screens" right now. I've tried changing every single other option in that box

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same issue, on multiple PCs with different PDFs, since upgrading to Adobe Reader DC.